How to mock multiple refs (and refs in general) in Nuxt?
I'm looking for a way to mock multiple refs (and refs in general) in Nuxt? I'm using Vitest and Nuxt test utils.
About my Case:
I want to test a SideBar.vue component. The component has multiple refs:
const isCollapsed = ref(false);
const tokens = ref(0);
const path = ref(useRoute().path); // I mock the value of this by mocking useRoute

I want to test,...
a) if the isCollapsed boolean is toggled when clicking a button
b) if the Tokens are displayed in the html.
Thanks for your help!

It's unclear what you ask about. What did you try and what did not work? Please, provide tested and testing code

Also why would you need to use refs for such a purpose? You can use test-ids or something alike to check the inputs/outputs of your tests. Otherwise, Nuxt uses refs in a regular way (just as Vue).
